# Flex/air or google gears or other

Tags: apache-flex, air, google-gears

I'm starting a new project divided into two parts: a php application and a desktop application that will use information from the php application.

The desktop application needs to meet the following requirement :

- easy to install
- easy to launch
- allow off-line data view
- allow synchronization with php app.

which solution is better  Flex/air or google gears or other ?

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google gears will allow off-line data view, but to create a stand-alone desktop application you'll need AIR or something similiar (you can combine Gears with ie. GWT and run in with AIR, or use Flex).

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR ticks all the boxes and of course, if you want to deliver a web-based interface too, you'll enjoy massive code re-use by building that in Flex. I'm currently using the Zend framework for my Flex/Air/Php development and it's doing fine - I recommend that.

Jamie.